# What's a good design for making sure the Node.js Event Loop isn't blocked when adding potentially hundreds of records?

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I just read this article from Node.js: [Don't Block the Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/)

**The Ask**

I'm hoping that someone can read over the use case I describe below and tell me whether or not I'm understanding how the event loop is blocked, and whether or not I'm doing it.  Also, any tips on how I can find this information out for myself would be useful.

**My use case**

I think I have a use case in my application that could potentially cause problems.  I have a functionality which enables a group to add members to their roster.  Each member that doesn't represent an existing system user (the common case) gets an account created, including a dummy password.

The password is hashed with argon2 (using the default hash type), which means that even before I get to the need to wait on a DB promise to resolve (with a Prisma transaction) that I have to wait for each member's password to be generated.

I'm using Prisma for the ORM and Sendgrid for the email service and no other external packages.

A take-away that I get from the article is that this is blocking the event loop.  Since there could potentially be hundreds of records generated (such as importing contacts from a CSV or cloud contact service), this seems significant.

To sum up what the route in question does, including some details omitted before:

- Remove duplicates (requires one DB request & then some synchronous checking)
- Check remaining for existing user
- For non-existing users:
- 1. Synchronously create many records & push each to a separate array.  One of these records requires async password generation for each non-existing user
- 2. Once the arrays are populated, send a DB transaction with all records
- 3. Once the transaction is cleared, create invitation records for each member
- 4. Once the invitation records are created, send emails in a MailData[] through SendGrid.

Clearly, there are quite a few tasks that must be done sequentially. If it matters, the asynchronous functions are also nested: createUsers calls createInvites calls sendEmails.  In fact, from the controller, there is:  updateRoster calls createUsers calls createInvites calls sendEmails.

Comment: It’s not clear exactly what you’re asking here, all this is really is just laying out a fact pattern specific to your scenario. Mind editing to clarify the ask? [ask].

Comment: Also, if your question is going to be "how should I implement this?": that's going to be too broad of a question. I would recommend starting with a minimal example to test your hypotheses that your use case may cause issues.

Comment: I already have it implemented - however shoddily that may be.  What I'm hoping for is for someone to tell me whether it seems like I'm on the right track with my understanding of the event loop based on the example I lay out in my use case.

Comment: @MichaelJay we don't know how you implemented the code for this, which modules you use, which Argon2 variant you use, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are architectural patterns that are aimed at avoiding issues brought by potentially long-running operations. Note here that while your example is specific, **any** long running process would possibly be harmful here.

The first obvious pattern is the **cluster**. If your app is handled by multiple concurrent independent event-loops of a cluster, blocking one, ten or even thousand of loops could be insignificant if your app is scaled to handle this.

Imagine an example scenario where you have 10 concurrent loops, one is blocked for a longer time but 9 remaining are still serving short requests. Chances are, users would not even notice the temporary bottleneck caused by the one long running request.

Another more general pattern is a **separated long-running process service** or the **Command-Query Responsibility Segregation** (I'm bringing the CQRS into attention here as the pattern description could introduce more interesting ideas you could be not familiar with).

In this approach, some long-running operations are not handled directly by backend servers. Instead, backend servers use a Message Queue to send requests to yet another service layer of your app, the layer that is solely dedicated to running specific long-running requests. The Message Queue is configured so that it has specific throughput so that if there are multiple long-running requests in short time, they are queued, so that possibly some of them are delayed but your resources are always under control. The backend that sends requests to the Message Queue doesn't wait synchronously, instead you need another form of return communication.

This auxiliary process service can be maintained and scaled independently. The important part here is that the service is never accessed directly from the frontend, it's always behind a message queue with controlled throughput.

Note that while the second approach is often implemented in real-life systems and it solves most issues, it can still be incapable of handling some edge cases, e.g. when long-running requests come faster than they are handled and the queue grows infintely.

Such cases require careful maintenance and you either scale your app to handle the traffic or you introduce other rules that prevent users from running long processes too often.